# Error Code When Trying to Connect to Microsoft Access DB in Python

Tags: python, ms-access

I receive the following error when trying to connect to an `MS Access DB` in  Python:

```
('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

This was the code block I used:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=S:\filepath\filename.accdb;')
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Seems like Python cannot find the .accdb file. Check name, full path and permissions on the disk if it's a network disk, and on the upper folders. Check if Python can open the file as a regular file too.

Comment: I've tried changing my Python environment to 32bit, because I wondered if there was an issue with the 32 bit Microsoft Access Driver connecting to 64-bit Python. I am still getting the error message. I also tried connecting to a DB on my local system (instead of shared drive), and I still get the error message.

Comment: I would try now to create a new DSN in the ODBC Data Sources. Call it TestAccess for example, use the Access driver and point it to the database you want. Then use in pyodbc:

`pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=TestAccess')`

Try defining it in both 32 and 64 ODBC, if possible.

Comment: @Julen That seems to work! I am struggling to create a Python 32 bit environment in any of my IDEs (I was just able to do so in the shell). How would I define the new DSN in both 32 and 64 ODBC?

Comment: To define the new DSN in 32 and 64, in Windows10 just search for "ODBC Data Sources" in the Windows button (left bottom of screen). Both should appear, one marked 32 bits and the other on 64 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause of the error message: compatibility issues between 64bit Python and 32bit Microsoft Access. After downloading the 64bit version of Microsoft Office, there is no longer an error when creating a connection with a Microsoft Access Database.